# Не работает перенаправление файлов в Wordpress через .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Сайт на Wordpress

Файлы картинок в папке темы: `/wp-content/themes/тема/img/.*`

Хочу, чтобы к файлам картинок можно было обратиться короче `/img/.*`

Пишу в /htaccess:
**`RewriteRule /wp-content/themes/тема/img/(.*)  img/$1 [L]`**

По адресу `сайт.ру/img/logo.png` выдает 404 страницу

При этом правила перенаправления с http и www работают

*Перепробовал все возможные и невозможные комбинации, всё время 404. Как быть?*

---

2 коммента и оба в точку - благодарю!

```
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$  /wp-content/themes/botanica/img/$1 [L]
```

1. Я перепутал стороны выражения: должно быть слева урл, справа серверный путь. Указание на начала строки, чтобы не затирались админские картинки/стили
2. Свои выражения нужно размещать над стандартной вставкой вордпресса: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: Лучше весь файл .htaccess показать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас перепутаны местами левая и правая части:

```
RewriteRule    img/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/тема/img/$1 [redirect=temp,last]
```

Проверил правило - работает.